# How to redirect after successful login and register in Flask-Security? And Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, redirect, flask, flask-security

How to redirect with successful register to a different html page than Default:'/'
redirect say to the profile page of the user logged in.

and after registering I have this error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run

  File "/home/maharshi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 659, in inner

  File "/home/maharshi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 499, in serve_forever

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 236, in serve_forever

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 585, in set

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 407, in notifyAll

<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

The data gets registered but this error is still there.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import render_template
from flask import request, redirect, url_for
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, UserMixin, RoleMixin, login_required
import datetime


#Create app
app= Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG']= True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= 'postgresql://postgres:mah@localhost/pdb1'
app.config['SECRET_KEY']= 'MaharshI'
app.config['SECURITY_REGISTERABLE'] = True

#Create database connection object
db= SQLAlchemy(app)

#Define models
roles_users= db.Table('roles_users', db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id')))

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id= db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name= db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    description= db.Column(db.String(225))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    roles= db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users, backref=db.backref('user',lazy='dynamic'))

#setup Flask-Security
user_datastore= SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security= Security(app, user_datastore)

# @app.before_first_request
# def create_user():
#   user_datastore.create_user(email='mah@m.com', password='pass')
#   db.session.commit()

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/profile/<email>')
@login_required
def profile(email):
    user= User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    return render_template('profile.html', user=user)

# SECURITY_POST_LOGIN_VIEW= 'snd.html'


# @app.route('/login_form')
# def login_form():
#   SECURITY_POST_LOGIN_VIEW= '/templates/snd.html'
#   return render_template(url_for(SECURITY_POST_LOGIN_VIEW))

# @app.route('/post_user', methods=['POST'])
# def post_user():
#   user=User(request.form['email'], request.form['password'])
#   db.session.add(user)
#   db.session.commit()
#   return redirect(url_for('home'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: @security.login_context_processor
def security_login_processor():
 SECURITY_POST_LOGIN_VIEW= '/templates/snd.html'
 return render_template(url_for(SECURITY_POST_LOGIN_VIEW)) #is this close ???

Comment: Post the entire error traceback, not just the final error message.

Comment: @JohnGordon please take a look ...

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is as a result of the Miscellaneous setting "`SECURITY_SEND_REGISTER_EMAIL`" which defaults to true, causing the your app to attempt to send a registration mail on successful registration. If you have not initialized the flask mail with an app instance, it raises this exception.

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Setting "`SECURITY_SEND_REGISTER_EMAIL = False`" solves this issue.